# Generating Heat map from scatter (x,y) data and then plot the same over an image using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

**WHAT I am trying to do:** I am trying to create a heatmap from these data points (x,y) and then superimpose that over the image that I used originally to collect these data points.

**Context:** I had floated a small survey where I showed an image to the respondents and asked them to click on the best aspect of the image. In return i got the x,y data (where the x is % from left and y is % from top of the image). I renamed y as yInverse (since I am used to treating bottom left as the origin) and created another column y (100 - original y). My image size was 484 * 433 pixels. Since these 3 columns were in percentages, I multiplied each of x with 484 and yInverse and Y with 433 to arrive at click coordinates for each of the respondent.

Here is the image with the scatter data plotted on it. Here the data points are plotted correctly.
[Image with scatter data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCMi6.png)

**Code of the above image:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

mydf = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/anuyadav/Downloads/Data_Q12_220126/Q12_Text.csv")
mydf.head(2)

x = mydf['xactual']
yInverse = mydf['yInverseactual']
y = mydf['yactual']

im = plt.imread("C:/Users/anuyadav/Downloads/Data_Q12_220126/Edited_Doc.png", format = "png")
implot1 = plt.imshow(im,zorder=1,alpha=0.5,origin="upper")
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10,10]
plt.scatter(x,yInverse,c="r",zorder=2,s=10,alpha=0.5)
```

Here is the image with the heatmap superimposed on it. [Image with heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTZQe.png)
As you can see from the 2 images, the heatmap is not properly aligned with the scatter data.
Any help on this would be appreciated!

**Code:**

```
im = plt.imread("C:/Users/anuyadav/Downloads/Data_Q12_220126/Original_Doc.png", format = "png")
im = im[::-1,:,:]
implot1 = plt.imshow(im,zorder=1,alpha=0.5)
x = mydf['xactual']
yInverse = mydf['yInverseactual']
y = mydf['yactual']
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, yInverse, bins=(484,433))
heatmap = gaussian_filter(heatmap, sigma=16)

implot2 = plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=[0,484,0,433], cmap=cm.jet,zorder=2,alpha=.5)
plt.axis("off")
```

Comment: You might try something like `np.histogram2d(x, yInverse, bins=(np.arange(0,484),np.arange(0,433)))`.   With `bins=(484,433)` you get 484 bins between the smallest and largest x-values.

Comment: @JohanC that worked perfectly. Thanks man!

Comment: @JohanC Could you please explain why it worked? :D

Comment: Well, if you use `bins=(484,433)`, you get 484 equally-sized bins between the smallest and largest x-values. That is not what you want. You need to explicitly set bin edges that work with the given discrete values. See e.g. [Difference in histograms of a colored image using plt.plot v/s plt.hist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67856985/12046409) for a more visual explanation.